# Azure search - Get Max/Min with paging

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a large azure index with various fields, including integer fields.

Is it possible to do a search, and get the MAX, and MIN value of a given field for the entire result set, whilst only returning the first page?

I want to avoid having to do 2 searches to achieve this.

I am calling the index from C# Code.

Comment: if you want to do this on top of azure search resultset, you can do it with Linq.

Comment: Of course - but I'd need the entire result set for my query. I am requesting this in pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct functionality that returns the min and max values as part of a single query. However, you can use facets to solve many examples. A typical use case is when you need to implement a filter control in the UI, like a slider where the min/max is indicated.

Here is an example where I have a property called SomeInt. In my result set I have values ranging from 0 to 175. To my query I add facet=SomeInt and my response allows me to determine the min/max:

```
"@odata.count": 9473,
"@search.facets": {
    "SomeInt": [
        {
            "count": 2949,
            "value": 175
        },
        {
            "count": 95,
            "value": 70
        },
        {
            "count": 46,
            "value": 0
        }
    ]
},
```